# What's the deeper meaning behind Miriam's punishment?

Tags: egypt, tzaraas-negaim, miriam

It is classically explained that Miriam received tzaras for what she said about moshe and the reason her punishment was so harsh was being a holy person even a small mistake is magnified to be a bigger deal than if it was someone else.

However, when it comes to the six remembrances each day, “Remember what the L‑rd, your G‑d, did to Miriam on the way, when you went out of Egypt.” The emphasis here is on what G-d did to Miriam and specifically what G-d did to Miriam while we were leaving Egypt.

What is the connection between tzaras and leaving mitzryim?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much leaving Mitzraim as it is being on the road traveling. See the Rashbam on Devarim 24 8-9. The basic azhara is against lashon hara and tzaras. The Torah singles out Miriam's storyto point out that when it comes to being masgir someone and sending them out of the camp, we should be careful to follow through and not be blinded by their stature. The Torah also mentions that the episode happened while we were traveling to point out that even though the whole nation had to wait because of her, they still did. The Meshech Chochmah also says something along these lines, being that klal yisroel was waiting for seven days, it would have been easier to just cut off the nega, but that is not what they did. This proves how much we have to be careful with nigaim.